# How powerful is $ACC^0$ circuit class in average case?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, circuit-complexity, big-picture, communication-complexity, worst-case

We know that $NEXP$ is not in $ACC^0$ .

Does the result that $NEXP$ is not in $ACC^0$ also hold in average case?

That is given a boolean function in $NEXP$ is it known that for every input length $n$ we cannot have $\frac1{n^c}$ ($c>0$) fraction of possible computable in $ACC^0$?

Tying up with communication complexity I think what I seek could be the following. Since $NEXP$ is not in $ACC^0$ is known could it be that any $NEXP$ complete function has superpolylogarithmic communication complexity in NOF model with superpolylogarithmic number of players?

Then the query is could the randomized complexity still be just logarithmic. Is this possible?

---

Generally speaking what is the smallest class $\mathcal C$ that is known such that given a boolean function in $\mathcal C$ it is known that for every input length $n$ we cannot have $\frac1{n^c}$ ($c>0$) fraction of possible inputs computable in $ACC^0$?

Comment: Your "tying up" comment gets things backwards. NOF lower bounds imply ACC0 lower bounds, but I don't think the other direction is necessarily true. Also for your question not to be trivial, you want the probability of error to be strictly less than 1/2.

Comment: @SashoNikolov I initially had much less than $1/2$. I will change it.

Comment: @SashoNikolov sorry I thought logarithmic communication complexity also implies problem is in ACC^0? Is it not true?

Comment: Due to widespread applicability of telescope protocols like the one by Grolmusz for GIP, even a superlogarithmic number of players has only yielded trivial lower bounds for explicit functions (let alone a superpolylogarithmic number of players).  In one of your questions you are therefore asking if NEXP-complete functions are immune to telescope protocols, and more.

Comment: @AndrásSalamon I think they are immune to this variety of protocols.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There seem to be typos in what you wrote; I take it you're asking: *is there a function $f \in NEXP$ such that for all polynomials $p$ and infinitely many $n$, no ACC0 circuit of $p(n)$ size can compute $f_n$ on more than $1-1/p(n)$ inputs of length $n$*?

As far as I know, this is open. But here is a possible path to doing it. We know that every $NEXP$-complete function $f$ does not have ACC0 circuits of polynomial size. Perhaps an arithmetization of some $f$ (representing $f$ naturally as a family of multilinear polynomials) over a large field of finite characteristic (e.g. characteristic two) would work. (Arithmetizations can typically give you average-case hardness "for free" ... but one would have to carry out the finite field arithmetic in ACC0, presumably.) Cite me if you figure it out. ;)

Comment: @RyanWillians actually I think that would be little strong than what I ask. I just ask if we can show no $ACC0$ circuit of $p(n)$ size can compute $f_n$ on more than $1/p(n)$ inputs of length $n$ (so $<1/2$ fraction and I think what you say is $>1/2$ fraction - I understand if circuit is generic and works on random such fraction we can get to $>1/2$ by repeating - but can we even get $1/p(n)$ in first place - may be helpful where repetitions are not allowed or not possible?). Also do natural proof or other barriers affect such situations (where repetitions are impossible or quite non-obvious).

Comment: Also I think 'carry out the finite field arithmetic in ACC0' is likely a major open problem and may be impossible.

Comment: Regarding "no ACC0 circuit of p(n) size can compute $f_n$ on more than $1/p(n)$ inputs of length $n$" As the other answer to this question says, some ACC0 circuit of O(1) size will always compute $f_n$ on at least a $1/2$ fraction of inputs of length $n$, which is the negation of what you're asking when $p(n) \geq 2$.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on how your phrasing is to be parsed.

In any case, the constant functions from ​ {0,1}<sup>*</sup> ​ to {0,1} are both in ACC<sup>0</sup>

and for all languages L and non-negative integers n, at least one of

those constant functions agrees with L on at least 1/2 of the n-bit strings.

You might be interested in ["errorless" heuristics](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/830d/11b1a70c1e6fb81339e5d5a9f9335f4f07b5.pdf).

Comment: corrected 'growing $f(n)$'.

Comment: changed my f ​ ​

Comment: ok updated mine to what I mean by growing.

Comment: I edited to point to the current issue. ​ ​

Comment: Do I still have an issue? Also $\omega(1)\neq O(1)$ and so the function could still grow.

Comment: Yes. ​ [Fractions of the inputs on which something is computable] are at most 1, so for sufficiently large n, we cannot have $\omega(1)$ fraction of inputs computable. ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: I have changed my problem scaling. It is no longer $\omega(1)$ and $o(2^n)$ so your argument will not work.

Comment: He was just pointing that you are using word fraction incorrectly. You want to say $\frac{2^n}{f(n)}$ inputs, rather then "fraction of inputs."

Comment: It also not clear what exactly you mean by "fraction of inputs computable in $ACC0$?". Do you want to have agreement on $(1/2 + \epsilon)$ fraction of inputs for some $\epsilon$? Or there is a fraction of inputs, such that corresponding partial function is hard?

Comment: @ivmihajlin well even if it works for $\frac1{2^{n^c}}$ ($c\in(0,1)$) fraction of possible inputs with an $ACC^0$ circuit that would be ok. No need for constant fraction.

Comment: @AJ so, the definition of complexity you are interested is: the smallest number $c$, such that $\forall S$ - subset of inputs, size of the smallest $ACC_0$ circuit that agrees with $f$ on S is $\leq c$. Right?

Comment: I ask if for $\frac1{f(n)}$ fraction of inputs if an $ACC^0$ circuit computes $f$ then what is the largest class that is known that $f$ can belong to? In opposite way if there is no $ACC^0$ circuit that can do the job for this fraction what is the smallest class we have separation from $ACC^0$.

Comment: @AJ. : ​ ​ ​ That class is probably [ALL](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:A#all). ​ For the opposite way, I'm not aware of anything for ACC0 that doesn't also work for P/poly. ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: 'gargantuan beast'.

Comment: @RickyDemer then please interpret it in all possible sensible ways. I am done updating.